# Application deployment exception

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, deployment

I have created WPF application which has connection to MDF files.In the solution folder I added my **MDF** file and its respective **LDF**. I added SQL Server Compact all the  DLL's to the folder ([as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983340%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

**Connection string** in my App config looks like

```
    <add key="Connection" value="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
       AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Public\Desktop\SomeDB.mdf;
       Integrated Security=True;"/>
```

But after Deployment when I run my exe I am getting following Exception

> Could not open new database 'C:\USERS\PUBLIC\DESKTOP\SomeDB.MDF'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Public\Desktop\SomeDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>
> File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\SomeDB_log.ldf" may be incorrect.
>
> The log cannot be rebuilt when the primary file is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

In Solution Explorer, right click your database file and select Properties. Make sure the "Copy to Output Directory" item is selected as "Copy always".

Now, every time you compile your application, your original database file is copied to the Debug folder